# How to conditionally show Get.bottomSheet when starting app

Tags: flutter, api, conditional-statements, frame, bottom-sheet

I am trying to popup Get.bottomSheet when starting app.

I did it like bottom code.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  _popUpBottomBanner();
}

void _popUpBottomBanner() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
    (_) {
      Get.bottomSheet(
        ...
      );
    },
  );
}
```

But I want to judge show or hide bottom sheet by API result.

So I changed Code like below.

```dart
void _popUpBottomBanner() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
    (_) {
      FutureBuilder<CustomListVO>(
        future: Api().getBanners(...),
        builder: (BuildContext _, AsyncSnapshot<CustomListVO> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return;
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return;
          if (snapshot.data?.list?.isNotEmpty == true) {
            Get.bottomSheet(
              ...
            );
          }
          return;
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Despite confirming API result arriving properly,

bottomSheet isn't showing.

What is the problem with this code?

Thanks for reading :D

====== resolved like below ========

```dart
@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {     
  return FutureBuilder<CustomListVO>(         
    future: Api().getBanners(...),         
    builder: (BuildContext _, AsyncSnapshot<CustomListVO> snapshot) {           
      if (snapshot.data?.list?.isNotEmpty == true) {             
        Get.bottomSheet(               
          ...             
        );           
      }
      return HomePage();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: If someone post current answer, you can upvote and mark as answer to thank, And don't include answer on question section, you can include it  on answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to show bottom sheet that is not required to use Futurebuilder so you can use it like this :

```
var result = await Api().getBanners(...);
if (result.data?.list?.isNotEmpty == true) {
        Get.bottomSheet(
          ...
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I could resolve that similar way with your answer!

Comment: You're welcome, you can mark your question as resolved if it's good for you.